# Execute script tag at the end of load of DOM to browser

Tags: javascript, html, user-controls

I want to transfer some values of variables from js file to the user control having script tag in which variables are to be accessed for manipulation. But I am unable to get value of variables. So kindly let me know how the variables can be passed from js to another js or usercontrol having script tag. I think that control is loaded first then it have values unknown so it gives error and js is loaded after that.  Kindly help me someone.

example like this

```
<script src="myjs.js">
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
--- Some code for manipulation 
</SCRIPT>
<div>
   <table>
    -------- some more structure here 
   </table>
</div>
```

i want to execute the tags in sequence like div table and all structure, then load external java script file and at last internal code of the script tag is to be executed.

Comment: Very hard to figure out what you're asking, I'm afraid, can you explain more what you think the pieces are and where you're trying to move the data from and to?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do, but a good start would be to place your external file at the end of your page (just before </body>), and in your external script, listen for the DOM ready or document loaded event.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can move the entire script tag to the bottom.
2. For external referenced scripts, you can use the `defer` argument on the script tag.
3. Or, the way that everyone else does it, add a event handler on the page to be triggered on page load

   ```
   window.onload = function() { everything in dom is there }
   ```

And this function can be in the header or wherever inside the page. The function won't be triggered until the page is loaded.